# Tabs disappear when starting activity from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, tabs, broadcastreceiver

I have to 2 tabs in my app.
In my onReceive function of BroadcastReceiver, i start a new activity (that is in tab 1 normally) with flag "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)".

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setClass(context, SomeActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

It starts ok but tabs are gone.

What should be done here (any other flags maybe) ?

Comment: Please add the code you are using to start the activity.

Comment: you can't startup activity, without initializing TabWidget, isn't it?